# Calculate hours between shifts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

There is a new law going into effect in one of the cities we operate in which states we must have a minimum of 11 hours from the time someone clocks-out until they can clock-in.  If the time is less than 11 hours, we must pay them a set amount of money for each occurrence.

I am using SQL Server 2012

I need help in determining which how many hours each person has between shifts.  Based on the records below, we would owe for 11/14 11:28pm --> 11/15 8:56am (9.28 hrs) and 11/29 2:32am --> 11/29 10:11am (7.39 hrs)

```
CREATE TABLE #Shift(
    FKEmployeeNumber int,
    DateOfBusiness datetime,
    FKStoreId int,
    EmployeeShiftNumber int,
    FKJobCodeId int,
    InHour int,
    InMinute int,
    OutHour int,
    OutMinute int)

insert into #Shift ( FKEmployeeNumber, DateOfBusiness, FKStoreId, EmployeeShiftNumber, FKJobCodeId, InHour, InMinute,OutHour,OutMinute)
values
(529251, '11/13/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 8, 1, 16, 24),
(529251, '11/14/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15, 21, 23, 28),
(529251, '11/15/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 8, 56, 15, 58),
(529251, '11/16/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 14, 59, 20, 54),
(529251, '11/19/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 12, 40, 19, 42),
(529251, '11/20/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 8, 28, 23, 47),
(529251, '11/21/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15, 31, 23, 30),
(529251, '11/25/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 10, 26, 18, 13),
(529251, '11/27/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 9, 58, 18, 27),
(529251, '11/28/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 14, 59, 2, 32),
(529251, '11/29/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 10, 11, 17, 13),
(529251, '11/29/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 17, 16, 17, 25),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15,4, 20, 0),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 20, 0, 23, 18),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 2, 1, 23, 18, 23, 22),
(529251, '12/01/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 12, 12, 16, 0)


Select 
sh.dateofbusiness,sh.fkstoreid,sh.employeeshiftnumber,sh.fkemployeenumber, sh.fkjobcodeid,sh.inHour,sh.InMinute,sh.OutHour,sh.OutMinute
 from #shift sh where sh.dateofbusiness > '11/12/2017' and sh.fkemployeenumber = 529251
order by sh.FKEmployeeNumber, sh.DateOfBusiness
```

Comment: You have mistakenly stored time as separate integer fields for each timepart. This is going to be not-fun as a result. I would suggest, to start, that you convert those things back into a proper timestamp data type so you can just subtract one record from the next using `LAG(yourtimestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY FKEmployeeNumber ORDER BY DateOfBusiness DESC)` to get the previous time-entry detail for your current record, otherwise you will be in for a world of hurt.

Comment: We get the data replicated to us from our POS provider.  The Hours and minutes are in separate columns, so I have no control over this.

Comment: Is POS short for Piece of Sh**? ;)  I think, though, that the real question here is how to properly convert your In time and Out time into a proper timestamp, then you can use LAG() to get your previous out time and subtract that from your current records in time. Convert, then subtract using Lag() and you are golden.

Comment: @JNevill I believe POS is short for Point of Sale. And storing `date(time)` values as `int` is not always a bad thing. Microsoft themselves do it in the `MSDB` configurations. For example, look at the docs for columns like `active_start_time` on [msdb.dbo.sysschedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysschedules-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way after creating some date times... using a cte and self join.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Shift') is not null
drop table #Shift

CREATE TABLE #Shift(
    FKEmployeeNumber int,
    DateOfBusiness datetime,
    FKStoreId int,
    EmployeeShiftNumber int,
    FKJobCodeId int,
    InHour int,
    InMinute int,
    OutHour int,
    OutMinute int)

insert into #Shift ( FKEmployeeNumber, DateOfBusiness, FKStoreId, EmployeeShiftNumber, FKJobCodeId, InHour, InMinute,OutHour,OutMinute)
values
(529251, '11/13/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 8, 1, 16, 24),
(529251, '11/14/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15, 21, 23, 28),
(529251, '11/15/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 8, 56, 15, 58),
(529251, '11/16/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 14, 59, 20, 54),
(529251, '11/19/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 12, 40, 19, 42),
(529251, '11/20/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 8, 28, 23, 47),
(529251, '11/21/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15, 31, 23, 30),
(529251, '11/25/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 10, 26, 18, 13),
(529251, '11/27/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 9, 58, 18, 27),
(529251, '11/28/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 14, 59, 2, 32),
(529251, '11/29/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 10, 11, 17, 13),
(529251, '11/29/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 17, 16, 17, 25),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 15,4, 20, 0),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 1, 1, 20, 0, 23, 18),
(529251, '11/30/2017', 3013, 2, 1, 23, 18, 23, 22),
(529251, '12/01/2017', 3013, 0, 1, 12, 12, 16, 0)


;with cte as(
select 
    FKEmployeeNumber
    ,DateOfBusiness
    ,FKStoreId
    ,EmployeeShiftNumber
    ,FKJobCodeId
    ,clockin = cast(convert(varchar(10),DateOfBusiness,101) + ' ' + right('00' + cast(InHour as varchar),2) + ':' + right('00' + cast(InMinute as varchar),2) as datetime)
    ,clockout = cast(convert(varchar(10),DateOfBusiness,101) + ' ' +  right('00' + cast(OutHour as varchar),2) + ':' + right('00' + cast(OutMinute as varchar),2) as datetime)
from
    #Shift),

cte2 as(
select *, RN = row_number() over (partition by FKEmployeeNumber order by clockin)
from cte)

select
    c.FKEmployeeNumber
    ,c.DateOfBusiness
    ,c.FKStoreId
    ,c.EmployeeShiftNumber
    ,c.FKJobCodeId
    ,c.clockin
    ,c.clockout
    ,nexClockInHourDifference = datediff(minute,c.clockout,c2.clockin) / 60.0
from cte2 c
left join cte2 c2 on c2.FKEmployeeNumber = c.FKEmployeeNumber and c2.RN = c.RN + 1

drop table #Shift
```

Also, since you are on 2012, you can use LEAD here and remove the `row_number()` function....

```
;with cte as(
select 
    FKEmployeeNumber
    ,DateOfBusiness
    ,FKStoreId
    ,EmployeeShiftNumber
    ,FKJobCodeId
    ,clockin = cast(convert(varchar(10),DateOfBusiness,101) + ' ' + right('00' + cast(InHour as varchar),2) + ':' + right('00' + cast(InMinute as varchar),2) as datetime)
    ,clockout = cast(convert(varchar(10),DateOfBusiness,101) + ' ' +  right('00' + cast(OutHour as varchar),2) + ':' + right('00' + cast(OutMinute as varchar),2) as datetime)
from
    #Shift)


select
    c.FKEmployeeNumber
    ,c.DateOfBusiness
    ,c.FKStoreId
    ,c.EmployeeShiftNumber
    ,c.FKJobCodeId
    ,c.clockin
    ,c.clockout
    ,nexClockInHourDifference = datediff(minute,c.clockout,lead(c.clockin) over(partition by FKEmployeeNumber order by clockin)) / 60.0
from cte c

drop table #Shift
```